# CSS is there a way to set spacing between an image and text within the same class?

Tags: css, image, text, position

I'm trying to set a class in css to display an image and a string after the image. The problem is the image and text overlap. Is there a way to put spacing between the image and text within the same class? Here is my code:

```
.innerTitle {
display: inline;
background-image: url(../images/tsegs_squigs.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left center;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: a little html code ? width on inline element has no effects.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifying anything but this class. If I have to make another class, or insert any html code it will require a lot more work since I would have to update like 20 different php files.

Comment: Something like that shouldn't be done using an inline element, even if there's tricks to achieve what you want, it is better to update all those 20 pages.

Comment: I was asking for a piece of rel life html going with that class , size of image. padding will set any room needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to css class:

```
{text-indent:50px;} Or
{text-indent:<width of background image>px;}
```

Comment: Thanks Ani. That worked. Also worth noting, I had to remove {display: inline;}

Comment: Text indent might not work if your string wraps onto multiple lines, since only the first line will have the spacing.

Comment: padding is much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to your element, since padding increasing the size of the element that  the background will show up on. Padding will only work on block and inline-block elements.

```
.innerTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: <width of background image>px
}
```